# Making my own installer

Tags: c#, installation, silent

Hello every1 my first ever question so go easy lol i am trying to make an installer that installs .net2.0 then the .net mysql connector then .net4.0

i need to do it in this order and i need them all to be silent and

lets say .net 2 gets half way done and somehow the installer gets quitted i need it to repair instead of fresh install but i need it to figure it out by itself.The only languages i know a bit about is c++ and c# if there is any way that would be very good! if people need more info go ahead and ask

Comment: Do you use visual Studio? because it has got a nice highly configurable installer creator.

Comment: Just use the Visual Studio installer-maker and check Fx2 and Fx4 in the prerequisites.

Comment: yeah i use visual studio express which i dont think has an installer creator :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also look into [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is a xml based scripting language, pretty easy to get started with, I think.

Just remembered that I once had a simular "task", I solved it using wix. I made an installer using Wix and created a bootloader that contained the software that was to be installed.

Furthermore, if an UI is needed for the scripting [wixeditor](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) is ok.

A good getting started tutorial for Wix, [Wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial)

Comment: Yes, WIX is the best open source tool for installation. I am using it since around 2 years and am satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at already existing installer systems?

Perhaps [Nullsoft](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), or [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), suits your needs.

You can script them according to your requirements.

Comment: i am having a look at this nullsoft thing and it seems really really confusing